Getting warnings while uploading app on the play store

I got these 3 warnings while uploading my app on the playstore. I tried searching on internet but did not get solution. Can someone tell what it is about(specially the first one)?
Gradle File
android {
compileSdkVersion 34
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.16"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_MODE", "\"PROD\""
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_MODE", "\"UAT\""
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}

buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true

}

You've changed something in your manifest - perhaps compatible-screens - which will cause Google Play to limit which devices it offers your app to.

for the bottom two errors, Can you share your grade file?

added the gradle file, please have a look.
